# I get an empty hide in file database

Tags: xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnifq.png)

> 1054 - Unknown column 'dept_emp.emp_no`emp_no' in 'group statement' CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW`dept_emp_latest_date `AS SELECT`dept_emp`.`emp_no`AS`emp_no`, max(`dept_emp`.`from_date`) AS` from_date`, max(`dept_emp`.`to_date`) AS` to_date`FROM`dept_emp`GROUP BY`dept_emp`.`emp_no``emp_no`;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (with explanation).